# Como puedo evitar que el reloj digital se mueva a los costados?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Cuando cambian los segundos el reloj se mueve para los costados según el tamaño de los dígitos

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector(".second-hand");
const minHand = document.querySelector(".min-hand");
const hourHand = document.querySelector(".hour-hand");
const digTime = document.querySelector(".time");

secondsBase = 0;
minutesBase = 0;
hoursBase = 0;

function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();
  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const hours = now.getHours();

  const time = [hours.toString(), minutes.toString(), seconds.toString()];

  const secondDegrees = (seconds / 60) * 360 + 90 + secondsBase;
  secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDegrees}deg)`;

  if (seconds == 59) secondsBase += 360;

  const minutesDegrees = (minutes / 60) * 360 + 90 + minutesBase;
  minHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesDegrees}deg)`;

  if (minutes == 59) minutesBase += 360;

  const hoursDegrees = (hours / 24) * 360 + 90 + hoursBase;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursDegrees}deg)`;

  if (hours == 11) hoursBase += 360;

  for (let i in time) {
    if (time[i].length === 1) {
      time[i] = 0 + time[i];
    }
  }
  digTime.innerText = `${time[0]} : ${time[1]} : ${time[2]}`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Squada+One&display=swap");

html {
  background: #018ded url(https://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=881&blur=5);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "helvetica neue";
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 0 0 3px #efefef,
    inset 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px); /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.05s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1);
}

div > p > span.time {
  text-align: center;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-size: 8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Squada One", cursive;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>JS + CSS Clock</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p><span class="time"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="clock">
      <div class="clock-face">
        <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
        <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Usa una fuente [`monospace`](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace)

Comment: El consejo de @Triby es **la solución** debes usar una fuente de tamaño fijo, porque el efecto óptico de los signos delgados pasando a signos anchos y viceversa no es controlable de modo que tamaños fijos es la mejor aproximación. Puedes incluso intentar con un fondo que se asimile al espacio de despliegue de los mismos y el efecto se va a mantener. 0 -> 1 adelgaza aún con fuentes fijas y 1 -> 2 engorda (hay efectos que se dan en el nervio óptico y eso no lo controla el css)

Comment: Para mantenerlos en el mismo renglón si tienes control asignando el atributo `white-space: nowrap;` y dando un ancho mínimo adecuado. Aún en caso de no usar fuente de tamaño fijo